# How to split a number into its digits in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to Split a number into its digit (for example 4563 to 4 , 5 , 6 , 3 ) then addiction this digits. (for example: 4+5+6+3=18)

I can write code for  3 digit or  2 digit and ... numbers seperately but I cant write a global code for each number.

so this is my code for 2 digit numbers:

```
var a = 23
var b = Math.floor(a/10); // 2
var c = a-b*10; // 3
var total = b+c; // 2+3
console.log(total); // 5
```

and this is my code for  3 digit numbers:

```
var a = 456
var b = Math.floor(a/100); // 4
var c = a-b*100; // 56
var d = Math.floor(c/10); // 5
var e = c-d*10; // 6
var total = b+d+e; // 4+5+6
console.log(total); // 15
```

but I cant write a code to work with each number.How can I write a global code  for each number?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138064/sum-of-the-digits-of-a-number-javascript

Comment: I guess http://stackoverflow.com/a/7784630/3894168 is what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var num = 4563;
var sum = 0;
while(num > 0) {
  sum += num % 10;
  num = Math.floor(num / 10);
}
console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 5):

In modern browsers you can do an array operation like

```
var num = 4563;
var sum = ('' + num).split('').reduce(function (sum, val) {
    return sum + +val
}, 0)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nrkny915/)

where you first create an array digits then use reduce to sum up the values in the array

Answer (score 0):

This solution converts the number to string, splits it into characters and process them in the callback function (`prev` is the result from the previous call, `current` is the current element):

```
var a = 456;
var sum = a.toString().split("").reduce(function(prev, current){
    return parseInt(prev) + parseInt(current)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Do number%10(modulus)  and then number/10(divide) till the number is not 0

Comment: Something like this

var x= 3456;
var sum=0;
while(x>0)
{
 var a = x%10;
 sum=sum+a;
 x=x/10;
}

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following example is useful to you:

```
var text="12345";
var total=0;
for (i=0;i<text.length;i++)
{
  total+= parseInt(text[i]);
}    
alert(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would approach the problem.  The trick I used was to split on the empty string to convert the string to an array and then use `reduce` on the array.

```
function digitSum(n) {
    // changes the number to a string and splits it into an array
    return n.toString().split('').reduce(function(result, b){
        return result + parseInt(b);
    }, 0);
}
```

As mentioned by several other posters (hat tip to my commenter), there are several other good answers to this question as well.

Comment: There is already [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30025928) on this question from 2015 that suggests this approach. [Two in fact](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30025921).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution using ES6 arrow functions as call back.
- Convert the number into a string.
- Split the string into an array.
- Call the map method on that array.
- Callback function parse each digit to an array.

```js
let number = 65535;

//USING MAP TO RETURN AN ARRAY TO DIGITS
let digits = number.toString()
                    .split("")
                    .map(num => parseInt(num));
//OUTPUT TO DOM
digits.forEach(
  digit => 
  document.querySelector("#out").innerHTML += digit + "<br>"
);
```

```html
<p id="out"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You can cast input number to string, using .toString() method and expand it into array with spread (...) operator

```
const splitNumber = n => [ ...n.toString() ]
```

2) Another short way - using recursion-based solution like:

```
const splitNumber = n => n ? [ ...splitNumber(n/10|0), n%10 ] : []
```

Comment: Code with explanation is beautiful thing and it will help to understand concept.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="text-align:center; margin:auto;">
This script limits the number of characters in the INPUT field to those specified in the QUANT field.
<form>
<input name="" type="number" id="quant" value = "" style="padding:6px; margin:0.8em;" /><br />
<input name="" type="number" id="input" oninput="calc()" style="padding:6px;  margin:0.8em;" /><br />
<input type="reset" style="width:150px;padding:8px; margin:0.8em;">
</form>
<div id="digit"></div><br />
<script>
let input;
let out = '';
let total = '';
let quant = "";

function calc(){
  quant = document.getElementById('quant').value;
  input = document.getElementById('input').value;
  total = input.split('');
  if(total.length > quant){
      document.getElementById('input').value = "";
      for(i=0; i < quant; i++){
          document.getElementById('input').value += total[i];
      }
}
out = total.length - 1;
if(out < 0){
   out = 0;
}
document.getElementById('digit').innerText = "Quantity: " + out;
}
</script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).