# Sum all the digits of a number Javascript

Tags: javascript, numbers, sum, digits

I am newbie.

I want to make small app which will calculate the sum of all the digits of a number.

For example, if I have the number 2568, the app will calculate 2+5+6+8 which is equal with 21. Finally, it will calculate the sum of 21's digits and the final result will be 3 .

Please help me

Comment: If you treat the number as a string ('2568'), then split the string on every character (str.split('')), you will have every digit listed out separately in an array. Each digit is still a string, but you can then cast each to a number and add them up. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: How could I tell the script to take the number from a specific input instead of a given number?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/18hc4hgd/ my work so far

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sum of the digits of a number javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138064/sum-of-the-digits-of-a-number-javascript)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Basically you have two methods to get the sum of all parts of an integer number.

- **With numerical operations**

  Take the number and build the remainder of ten and add that. Then take the integer part of the division of the number by 10. Proceed.

```js
var value = 2568,
    sum = 0;

while (value) {
    sum += value % 10;
    value = Math.floor(value / 10);
}

console.log(sum);
```

- **Use string operations**

  Convert the number to string, split the string and get an array with all digits and perform a reduce for every part and return the sum.

```js
var value = 2568,
    sum = value
        .toString()
        .split('')
        .map(Number)
        .reduce(function (a, b) {
            return a + b;
        }, 0);

console.log(sum);
```

---

For returning the value, you need to addres the `value` property.

```
rezultat.value = sum;
//      ^^^^^^
```

```js
function sumDigits() {
    var value = document.getElementById("thenumber").value,
        sum = 0;

  while (value) {
      sum += value % 10;
      value = Math.floor(value / 10);
  }
  
  var rezultat = document.getElementById("result");
  rezultat.value = sum;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="number" id="thenumber"/><br/><br/>
<button onclick="sumDigits()">Calculate</button><br/><br/>
<input type="text" readonly="true" placeholder="the result" id="result"/>
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @Nina, why modulo 10 exactly? Would you mind expanding on that?

Comment: @Daniel, the remainder operator is for getting the digit for adding to sum.

Comment: for the second solution "Use string operations" If I use the number 0123 instead of 2568 answer is wrong.

Comment: @ChetanNada, numbers with leading zero are interpreted as octal values. please have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#numeric_literals).

Comment: @NinaScholz So what is the solution for this? if any number leads with zero then the answer is unexpected!

Comment: don't use constant values with leading zero.

Answer (score 39):

How about this simple approach using modulo 9 arithmetic?

```
function sumDigits(n) {
  return (n - 1) % 9 + 1;
}
```

Comment: Excellent example, though I personally do not fully get the idea how this works ... I mean, suppose `n = 12`, then `12-1 = 11`, `11 % 9 = 1` and `1 + 1 = 2`, yet it should be `3` ...

Comment: Actually `11 %  9 = 2`, not 1, so `1 + 2 = 3`

Comment: note: it finds the sum of digits *recursively* (it is not clear from the title of the question and the accepted answer)

Comment: @AlexShevyakov ignore the -1 and +1, then it is just n%9. Since a number n=10^k*a_k + 10^(k-1)*a_(k-1)...10^0*a_0. Modulo 9 removes all all 10^i, since 10^i mod 9 = 1. Then the sum is created modulo 9 as well. When you imagine -1 shifts the whole number line by one to the left, you get also the nines correctly. After that you simply add 1 again.

Comment: This is elegant! I had to read about modulo 9 arithmetic to understand it.

Comment: @FedericoAntonucci However, the function seems to fail if n % 9 = 1

Comment: @R3l1c not really, on which value for n you consider the function fails? For example taking 10: 10 % 9 = 1 -> (10 - 1) % 9 + 1 -> 9 % 9 + 1 -> 0 + 1 -> 1

Comment: @FedericoAntonucci Apparently it fails for all numbers greater than 10 which have remainder 1 on division with 9. For eg. 19, 28, 37, 46, ... and so on. The function should return 10 for these cases but instead returns 1.

Comment: @R3l1c the function should return rhe sum recursively, that's exactly what the question asks, read it again please. This solution works perfect for this question

Comment: This should be the answer. This is much faster and much more elegant

Comment: Usage of that function was a waste of time for me, because I didn`t need the recursive version of the sum. I needed a function that just give immediate (intermediate) sum of digits. And this function fails for that case as noted by @Raknos13.

Comment: Unfortunatelly it doesn't work all the time.

Comment: For example sumDigits(19) returns 1 instead of 2

Comment: 1 is the right answer. 1 + 9 = 10 -> 1 + 0 = 1

Comment: This returns 2 for 29 , (29-1)%9+1 = 28%9+1 = 1+ 1 =2 ,  but the expected result is 2+9 = 11

Comment: @ganesh the question was how to add recursively until getting only 1 digit, not to sum all digits. So 11 -> 1+1 = 2
Read the question again.

Answer (score 5):

> With mathy formula:

```
function sumDigits(n) { 
    return (--n % 9) + 1;
}
```

> Without mathy formula:

```
function sumDigits(n) {
    if (typeof n !== 'string') {
        n = n.toString();
    }    
    if (n.length < 2) {
        return parseInt(n);
    }
​
    return sumDigits(
        n.split('')
         .reduce((acc, num) => acc += parseInt(num), 0)
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

let's try recursivity

```
function sumDigits(n) {
  if (n < 10) return n
  return sumDigits(n % 10 + sumDigits(Math.floor(n / 10)))
}

sumDigits(2) // 2
sumDigits(2568) // 3
```

Answer (score 2):

The sum of digits can be calculated using that function (based on other answers):

```
function sumDigits(n) {
    let sum = 0;
    while (n) {
        digit = n % 10;
        sum += digit;
        n = (n - digit) / 10;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

If you really need to sum the digits recursively there is recursive version of the function:

```
function sumDigitsRecursively(n) {
    let sum = sumDigits(n);
    if (sum < 10)
        return sum;
    else
        return sumDigitsRecursively(sum);
}
```

The `sumDigitsRecursively(2568)` expression will be equal to `3`. Because `2+5+6+8 = 21` and `2+1 = 3`.

Note that [recursive solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47486307/710069) by @FedericoAntonucci should be more efficient, but it does not give you intermediate sum of digits if you need it.

Comment: The question is about recursive sum of digits

Comment: @FedericoAntonucci but you didn't name your function as `sumDigitsRecursively` and it did confised me, because I was looking for the method to just sumDigits. My answer contains solution that gives the same results as yours. Why did you voted my answer down?

Comment: cause recursive solution is no better than every other answer, and it's the less elegant solution

Comment: I got here when I was looking for just the sum of digits of the number, and the accepted answer do not contain a function that just receives the number and returns the sum. So I made it. Accepted solution makes a call to `Math.float`, but there is no need to do so. So for my task this is a better solution. Also the recursive version is only a bit less efficient than yours (and I wrote about it in the answer), but it is easy to understand. On the other hand you didn't explain how your solution work, and didn`t name it correctly so it caused the confusion for me and for @Raknos13.

Comment: I was just answering the question, it didn't ask for what you are saying, you should read the whole question, not just the title

Answer (score 2):

You could do it this way.

```
function sums(input) {
    let numArr = input.toString().split('');
    let sum = numArr.reduce((a, b) => Number(a) + Number(b));
    return sum < 10 ? sum : sums(sum);
}
```

Comment: It is a good solution for huge numbers of strings. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding upon @fethe 's answer, this `sumOfDigit` function is able to handle large number or `BigInt`

```js
function sumOfDigits(n) { 
  return (Number.isSafeInteger(n)) ? (--n % 9) + 1 : Number((--n % 9n) + 1n);
}

console.log(sumOfDigits(101)); // 2
console.log(sumOfDigits(84932)); // 8
console.log(sumOfDigits(900000000000000000000000009n)); // 9
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function and pass your number to it:

```
const solution = (n) => {
    const arr = `${n}`
    let sum = 0;
    for (let index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
        sum += parseInt(arr[index])
    }
    return sum;
}
```