# Sum up a number until it becomes 1 digit JS

Tags: javascript, math

Before you mark duplicate note that it isn't. Others didn't look for the exact same thing as me.

What is the most compact possible way to sum up a number in javascript until there is only one digit left. For example: You input 5678 then the script adds it together (5+6+7+8) and gets 26, but since its more than 1 digit it adds it again and gets 2+6=8.

Is there anyway to do this with a number of any size? And how compact can the script get?

Comment: Do you know about https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Is this meant to be [code-golfing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) ?

Comment: please add your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum all the digits of a number Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38334652/sum-all-the-digits-of-a-number-javascript)

Comment: no it isn't. The answers in that question are different and only get down to 2 digits.

Comment: @Vincent [This answer is only down to 2 digits?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47486307/47589)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you're looking for short, it's hard to beat:

```js
var n = 5678;
sum  = n % 9 || 9;

console.log(sum)
```

If you're curious about how that works, see: [casting out nines.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casting_out_nines)

Comment: cool! This is so smart way. While my approach looks more functional programming style :)

Comment: @Titus any idea how to fix it?

Comment: It seems to fail when the number is divisible by `9`. Probably to fix that, it will get more complicated then other solution.

Comment: @Titus, is there a case that isn't fixed with the simple edit?

Comment: I can't think of any and it seems to be logical since the result can never be `0`

Comment: @vincent, can you give an example? A few cases I've tried: 920 yields 2 which is correct, 931 yields 4, also correct.

Comment: 9999 or 1234567890 which is the number I need to test

Comment: @Vincent `9+9+9+9` == `36` `3+6` == `9` that's the answer I get. Same with `1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+0` =  `45` `4+5` ==`9` Also what I get. Are you sure you're getting the `n || 9` in the `console.log()`?

Comment: 9999 % 9 = 0. That's the flaw. Even if it gets to 9+9+9+9=36, 3+6=9, 9 % 9 = 0. It console logs 0.

Comment: @Vincent double check the last line — that's addressed.

Comment: @Mark_M do you think that `while` loop is really required ??

Comment: @ashwintastic no - of course not — that's really funny that I didn't notice that. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this using recursion, here is an example:

```js
function getOneDigit(nr){
    let asStr = nr.toString();
    let sum = asStr.split("").reduce((a, c) => {
         a+=parseInt(c);
         return a;
    }, 0);
    return sum >= 10 ? getOneDigit(sum) : sum;
}

[234235, 235346, 657234, 1, 2, 5423].forEach(nr => console.log(getOneDigit(nr)));
```

Answer (score 2):

This line of code does this.

```
function digital_root(n) {
    return (n - 1) % 9 + 1;
}
```

When you take the modulo of a number with 9, it becomes a 1 less than 9. 
So, when you have 10%9, you will get 1, which is equal to 1+0.

Similarly, 123%9 = 6.

Why (n-1)%9 and added 1:
Because when you input 9, it became 0 so input will be invalid.

For n=9, this method will return (9-1)%9 = 8 and 8+1 = 9.

So it does not break.

You can also write

```
return n%9 || 9
```

Comment: Please describe, what was the problem and how will this code solve it, to help others understand this answer

Answer (score 2):

```
function createCheckDigit(membershipId) {
     var total = membershipId;
   while (total.length > 1) {
       t = 0;
       for (let i = 0; i < total.length; i++) {
               t = Number(t) + Number(total[i]);
       }
       total = t.toString(); 
   }
   return total;
  }
console.log(createCheckDigit("55555"));
```

Comment: When answering an old question, your answer would be much more useful to other StackOverflow users if you included some context to explain how your answer helps, particularly for a question that already has an accepted answer. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

For a compact way, you could use an iterative and recursive approach.

```js
const d = n => n > 9 ? d([...n.toString()].reduce((a, b) => +a + +b)) : n;

console.log(d(5678));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the length of value (after converting `sum` to a `String`) is 1 or not.

```
var fnSum = (arr) => arr.reduce((a, c) => a + (+c), 0); //function to get sum of values

var fnGetSingleDigit = (arr) => {
  while (arr.length != 1) {
    var sum = fnSum(arr);
    arr = String(sum).split("");
  }
  return arr[0];
};

console.log(fnGetSingleDigit([5, 6, 7, 8]));

console.log(fnGetSingleDigit([41,34,3,54,63,46]));
```

**Demo**

```js
var fnSum = (arr) => arr.reduce((a, c) => a + (+c), 0); //function to get sum of values

var fnGetSingleDigit = (arr) => {
  while (arr.length != 1) {
    var sum = fnSum(arr);
    arr = String(sum).split("");
  }
  return arr[0];
};

console.log(fnGetSingleDigit([5, 6, 7, 8]));

console.log(fnGetSingleDigit([41,34,3,54,63,46]));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function fun(n) {
sum = 0;
while(n > 0 || sum > 9)
    {
        if(n == 0)
        {
            n = sum;
            sum = 0;
        }
        sum = sum+n % 10;
        n = Math.floor(n/10);
    }
    console.log(sum);
}
```

You can use the above snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```
function sumOfID(__id){
  var arr_str = Array.from(__id)
  var arr = arr_str.map((t)=>{return parseInt(t)})
  function digSum(__arr){
   return __arr.reduce((a,b)=>{return a + b})
  }
   return digSum(arr)%9 || 9    
 }
```

Note : 
The trick here is to use mod9 because the modulo 9 of any multiple digit number is its total sum until it becomes a single digit number.

Answer (score 0):

```
// recursive
    function digitSum(n) {
      return (n % 10 === n) ? n : (digitSum(n.toString().split('').reduce((acc, curr) => acc + parseInt(curr), 0)));
    }

    
        
   function digitSum(n) {
       while(!(n % 10 === n)) {
         n = n.toString().split('').reduce((acc, curr) => acc + parseInt(curr), 0);
       }
      
       return n;
    
    console.log(digitSum(467)); // -> 17 -> 8
```

basically check if the nums length (digit count length) < 2 (achieved this with *n % 10 === n* (9 % 10 === 9) or *n.toString().length < 2* if NOT then call the function again with calculated digit sum
take example 467:

1. 4 + 6 + 7 = 17 (digit length is not 1) call with 17
2. 1 + 7 = 8 (digit length is 1) -> return.
   2nd version is the same as recursive one, hope this helps!

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const a = [1,2,4,4,5,6,7,7].join('')

function add(i){
  let x = i.toString().split('').reduce((p,c)=>parseInt(p)+parseInt(c))
  x = x.toString().length > 1 ? add(x) : x
  return parseInt(x)
}


console.log(add(a))
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you go

```js
var number = 56785;
var total = number + '';
    
while(total.length > 1) {
   var temp = 0;
   for(var i = 0; i < total.length; i++) {
       temp += +total[i];
   }
   total = temp + '';
}
    
console.log(total);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also opt to use the `forEach` loop and a `while` condition to loop over the stringify number and get the sum until the length is 1.

```js
var num = 5678;
var strNum = num.toString().split('');
while(strNum.length !== 1){
  var strNum = calculateSum(strNum);
  strNum = strNum.split('');
}
var result = parseInt(strNum);
console.log(result);

function calculateSum(strNum){
  var sum = 0;
  strNum.forEach((digit)=>{
    sum += parseInt(digit);
  });
  return sum.toString();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is my solution for the same problem on CodeWars

```
const sumup = (num) => {
   let a = String(num).split('').map((k) => {
     return Number(k);
   }).reduce((p, c) => {
     return p + c;
   }, 0);

   return a > 9 ? sumup(a) : a;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a recursive solution without using any library!

```js
function getSumOfDigits(num){
  var result = 0;
  while(~~(num/10) > 0){
    result += (num % 10);
    num = ~~(num/10);
  }
  return result + num;
}

function getSingleDigit(num) {
  if(~~(num/10) === 0) {
    return num
  } else {
    num = getSumOfDigits(num);
    return getSingleDigit(num);
  }
}

console.log(getSingleDigit(393));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can combine some utility methods with recursion and do it in two lines that are still pretty readable:

```js
function sumDigits(digits) {
  let sum = Array.from(digits.toString()).map(Number).reduce((res, val) => res + val, 0);
  return sum < 10 ? sum : sumDigits(sum);
}

console.log(sumDigits(55555)) // 5+5+5+5+5 = 25 -> 2+5 = 7
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
function doSum(n){
 var temp = n, total= 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < n.toString().length; i++ ){
        total = total + (Math.floor(temp) % 10)
    temp = (temp / 10)
  }
 if(total > 9 ) { return doSum(total) }
return total
}
doSum(999999)
```