# how to call the function inside itself in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner in JavaScript and I faced this test on one of testing websites and they gave me this test which is a function that convert given number to checkId which is the sum of all digits of the given number for example:
given 237 its 2+3+7=12 12 is 1+2= 3 so the returned value should be 3
this is my code and the problem it gives me UNDEFINED please help
thank you

```js
function createCheckDigit(membershipId) {
  if (membershipId < 10) {
    return membershipId;
  } else {
    var digits = ("" + membershipId).split("");
    for (var i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
      digits[i] = parseInt(digits[i]);
    }
    var res = digits.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
    // recursion 
    createCheckDigit(res);
  }
}
document.write(createCheckDigit("450"));
```

Comment: In your first check, you pass a string in yet are checking against a number, this will never work `if(membershipId<10 )`

Comment: you are missin `return`, just add it to ` createCheckDigit(res);`

Comment: For a one-liner look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49892863/295783)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were just missing to return the result of the inner call :

```js
function createCheckDigit(membershipId) {
  if (membershipId < 10) {
    return membershipId;
  } else {
    var digits = ("" + membershipId).split("");
    for (var i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
      digits[i] = parseInt(digits[i]);
    }
    var res = digits.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
    // missing return here 
    return createCheckDigit(res);
  }
}
document.write( "450 => "+createCheckDigit("450"));
document.write( "<br>730 => "+createCheckDigit("730"));
document.write( "<br>480 => "+createCheckDigit("480"));
```

Answer (score 0):

In recursive function, if function returns the value then you must `return function call` too for get value.

Here is the solution  :

```js
function createCheckDigit(membershipId) {
  if (membershipId < 10) {
  console.log("member", membershipId);
    return membershipId;
  } else {
    var digits = ("" + membershipId).split("");
    console.log("digit", digits);
    for (var i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
      digits[i] = parseInt(digits[i]);
    }
    var res = digits.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
    console.log("result", res);
    // recursion 
    return createCheckDigit(res);
  }
}
document.write(createCheckDigit("450"));
```