# Summing a number's digits

Tags: javascript, algorithm

**My code below. Can someone see the mistake I made?**

Write a function named sumDigits which takes a number as input and returns the sum of the absolute value of each of the number's decimal digits. For example:

```
sumDigits(10);  // Returns 1
sumDigits(99);  // Returns 18
sumDigits(-32); // Returns 5
Let's assume that all numbers in the input will be integer values.

function sumDigits(number) {
  let numberstring = number.toString()
  let numberarr = numberstring.split("")
  let counter = 0
  for(var i=0; i<numberarr.length; i++) {
    if(typeof numberarr[i] === "number") {
        console.log(numberarr[i])
        let numbervalue = Number(numberarr[i])
        console.log(numbervalue)  
        counter += numbervalue
    } else if (typeof numberarr[i] !== "number"){
      counter += 0
    }
  } 
  return counter
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you get?

Comment: The problem is that `typeof numberarr[i] === "number"` will always be `false` because `numberarr` contains `string`s.

Comment: it's not going through the first if statement...

Comment: You can replace that with [isNaN(..)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum all the digits of a number Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38334652/sum-all-the-digits-of-a-number-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log(Math.abs(sumDigits(10)));  // Returns 1
console.log(Math.abs(sumDigits(99)));  // Returns 1
console.log(Math.abs(sumDigits(-32)));  // Returns 1 // Returns 5
//Let's assume that all numbers in the input will be integer values.

function sumDigits(number) {
  var counter = 0;
    var remainder;
    number=Math.abs(number);
        while(number>0){
            counter=counter+number%10;
            number=Math.floor(number/10);
        }
        return counter;
  }
```

I think you are looking for some code like this. i don't get why you convert your number to string.

```
number=Math.abs(number); this line first convert any negative number to positive.

sumDigits(number) takes an argument as now loop through the number until number < 0 then add the remainder to counter variable then return counter as final sum
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```js
console.log(sumDigits(-103));  // Returns 4

function sumDigits(number) {
    var numberstring = number.toString();

    var counter=0;
    for(var i=0; i<numberstring.length; i++){
        if(parseInt(numberstring.charAt(i))){
            counter += parseInt(numberstring.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: Try sumDigits(-103)

Answer (score 0):

This

> if(typeof numberarr[i] === "number")

statement is always false, because before you convert the number into a string. I think that your function return always zero.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by giovybus & Raman are correct, if you were wondering why your snippet didn't work - it's because the reference of the numberer[I] will always be a string. numberarr is a string array, not a number array, you needed to convert it to a number before using. Adjustments to your code above as below

```js
sumDigits(10);  // Returns 1
sumDigits(99);  // Returns 18
sumDigits(-32);

function sumDigits(number) {
  let numberstring = number.toString().replace("-", "");
  let numberarr = numberstring.split("")
  let counter = 0
   
  for(var i=0; i<numberarr.length; i++) {
    const numbervalue = Number(numberarr[i])
    if(typeof numbervalue === "number") {
        counter += numbervalue
    } else if (typeof numbervalue !== "number"){
      counter += 0
    }
  } 
  console.log(counter)
  return counter
}
```

However this is not a good solution and you should consider using solution by giovybus, Raman or anyone else with better approach instead.

Answer (score 0):

Using filter and reduce to calculate the total.

```js
function sumDigits(number) {
  return ( [...number.toString()]
    .filter( (char) => !isNaN(parseInt( char ) ) )
    .reduce( function(a,b) { return a + parseInt(b) }, 0) );
}
const sum1 = sumDigits(103);
console.log( sum1 );
const sum2 = sumDigits(-105);
console.log( sum2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Using latest ES6 syntax...

```
function sumDigits(num) {
    return [...num.toString()].map(Number).reduce((acc, val) => acc + val, 0);
};

console.log(sumDigits(55)); // 10
```

#### Explanation of tricky parts:

This will split the string into an array of digits:

```
[..."1234"] // => [ "1", "2", "3", "4" ]
```

This will transform it into Numbers

```
[ "1", "2" ].map(Number) //  => [ 1, 2 ]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).